# keep Focus on QGLWidget with QCheckBox and QPushButton in MainWindow

Tags: qt, focus, qglwidget

I have a Qt main window with QCheckBox and QPushButton and a sub QGLwidget class widget for graphics rendering.

I have put into `void Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)` member function :

```
void Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
{
   pushButton_2 = new QPushButton(widget);
...
   checkBox_3 = new QCheckBox(widget);
...
    widget_2 = new GLWidget(widget);
    widget_2->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    widget_2->setFocus();
...
}
```

I have created signals which modify the graphics rendering of `widget_2` :

```
void Ui_MainWindow::createSignals()
{ 
...
connect(pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(pauseSimu()));  
connect(checkBox_3, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(hideClassic()));     
...
}
```

To always keep the focus on `widget_2` despite clicking on `pushButton_2` or `checkBox_3`, I have to put into `pauseSimu()` and `hideClassic()` :

```
void Ui_MainWindow::pauseSimu()
{

widget_2->setFocus();

...

}
```

and

```
void Ui_MainWindow::hideClassic()
{

widget_2->setFocus();

...

}
```

The key events on `widget_2 GLWidget` are coded in the GLWidget class member functions.

How could I avoid to use `setFocus()` in all signals functions for always keeping the focus on `widget_2` GLWidget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)` on your button and checkbox.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much.